# How to handle bunch of json objects with different names

Tags: c#, json

the problem is that i dont know how to create model for json from api.
I used some online json to c# generator but it creates a very high count of classes what is unnecessary and very problematic with time.

thats my json:

> https://solomid-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/blitz/tft/data/items.json

Comment: Please include the exemple JSON directly in the question (preferably a small exemple that expose the error). Links tend to die with time and that would make your question unclear for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this model
    https://pastebin.com/SpGe72P7

and this serialization line

```
 Dictionary<string, TftItems> foo = Drzewo.Configuration.DeserializeJson<Dictionary<string, TftItems>>(data);
```

where Configuration.DeserializeJson is just generic function of

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)
```

Comment: Please include the exemple model directly in the question. Links tend to die with time and that would make your question unclear for future readers.